# How to change font of keyPreviewLayout in android virtual keyboard

Tags: android, fonts, keyboard

I want to change the font of preview layout in virtual keyboard.
I created a class that extends TextView and in constructor:

```
Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/MyFont.ttf");
this.setTypeface(mFont);
```

and created a layout:

```
<com.example.android.softkeyboard.KeyPreviewTextView ...
android:background="@drawable/keyboard_key_feedback" />
```

and set the layout:

```
android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/keyboard_key_preview"
```

but I see no change in font
can you help me?

Comment: Just a wild guess, have you tried changing the input method?

Comment: Sorry what did you mean?